# I'm trying to password protect my website and when i get the popup to login and i use my creds

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, md5

I always get this error:

> Internal Server Error 
>   ?The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@stage.mysite.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a

> 500 Internal Server Error 
>   error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>   Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_hive/4.0 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at stage.mysite.com Port 80

Here's what I've done in the htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile "/home/feli33/public_html/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

and in the root of the public html folder I have my `.passwd` file:

the only thing in it is a username and an md6 hash:

```
admin:li3fFizhXCgMU
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The closing quote is missing from the AuthUserFile "/home/feli33/public_html/.htpasswd line. You actually don't need any quotes there.

Comment: I noticed that just a little while ago and put an ending quote. I can't figure out for the life of me why it's not working. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: It must be something trivial. Can you post your whole virtual host config file.

Comment: Don't think you need the quotes around the `AuthUserFile` string

Comment: I'm sorry, where do i find that? @Boris... It's a magento EE store.

Comment: @thismethod I just posted answer with the configuration that worked fine on my test server. Where the MD6 hash is coming from. Is that even supported by apache APR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how my .htaccess looks like. I've created my .htpasswd file by running htpasswd -c .htpasswd username. The password is pass.

```
AuthType basic
AuthName "private area"
AuthUserFile "/var/www/path/to/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

Command to create .htpasswd file.

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd username
```

.htpasswd file.

```
username:$apr1$QC6hD31s$I/uGkzaIrnUp/5sSURRH00
```

Comment: I took out the md5 hash and i'm just trying to use a normal pw now and it's still not working. it's got to be something trivial in the configuration like you were thinking too.

Comment: Is there a certain place in the htaccess file this has to go.. top bottom middle?

Comment: @thismethod No that should be fine. How are you generating passwords?

Comment: I'm just using an alphanumeric word that i made up, i'm not generating them using anything anymore.

Comment: @thismethod I don't think you can do that unless your code is running on Windows. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/password_encryptions.html

Comment: I just ended up doing it through cpanel because it's been bothering me so much. Thanks for all your help though.